# Can I embed an entity within a intent

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

can I embed an entity in an intent,

eg

'what can a @DVD do'

entities for DVD have been set up a digital video disc, digital versatile disc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, create one intent with how to ask about features for your @DVD, create one Entity `@DVD` with your values: digital versatile disc, digital video disc, and with synonymous.

**One good Idea is to create one condition with the `Intent` alone and ask about "What DVD? You can choice: digital versatile disc, digital video disc". And in the next flow, you will create some nodes with your response. Like:**

```
 @DVD:(digital versatile disc)
 @DVD:(digital video disc)
```

[image]

**And After, create one flow with 2 conditions. Because if user have the intent and set the entitie in the same question, Watson will recognize. Check:**

```
#DVDWants AND @DVD:digital versatile disc
```

[image]

**Check examples:**

[image]

**Check Watson recognize:**

[image]

Comment: well, I was not looking to get the entity value in the subsequent dialog. 

This is my requirement, instead of setting up intents as :

What are the features of a DVD ,
What are the features of a digital video disc,
what are the features of a digital versatile disc,



I wanted to just set up the intent as:

What are the features of a @DVD